# Corollary of the De Morgan's Laws

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

People, I am trying to do my exercise list of the course of Measure Theory and I had a doubt about one "corollary" from the De Morgan's Laws. The De Morgan's law says that:

> For a family $\{E_\alpha; \alpha \in \Gamma \}$, where $\Gamma$ is some indexing set, of subsets of a universal set $\mathfrak{U}$, the following properties hold:
>
> - $\displaystyle\left(\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha\right)^c=\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha^c$
> - $\displaystyle\left(\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha\right)^c = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha^c$

I would like to know it is true that if $\Gamma$ a indexing set and $\{E_\alpha; \alpha \in \Gamma \}$ and $\{F_\alpha; \alpha \in \Gamma \}$ are families of subsets of a set $X$, then

1. $\displaystyle\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} (E_\alpha - F_\alpha) = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha - \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha$ and
2. $\displaystyle\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} (E_\alpha - F_\alpha) = \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha - \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha.$

I have already done the first side of que item 1. Have someone some idea if the other side holds?

Thank you very much, everybody!

Comment: **Example for 1. :** $\mathfrak U=\{1,2\}$, $\Gamma=\{a,b\}$, $E_a=F_a=\{1\}$, $E_b=F_b=\{2\}$. Then $\cup_{\alpha\in\Gamma}(E_\alpha-F_\alpha)=\emptyset$, while   $\cup_{\alpha\in\Gamma} E_\alpha-\cap_{\alpha\in\Gamma} F_\alpha = \{1,2\}-\emptyset = \{1,2\}$.

Comment: Thank you John Dawkins and Jimmy R. Thank you very much!

Comment: Example for 2: $E_{a} = \{1,2\}, F_{a} = \{1\}, E_{b} = \{2,3\}, F_{b} = \{2\}.$ Then $\bigcup E_{\alpha} - F_{\alpha} = \{2,3\}$ whereas $\bigcap E_{\alpha} - \bigcup F_{\alpha} = \emptyset$

Comment: @JohnDawkins can you help-me to see what is wrong in this $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} (E_\alpha - F_\alpha) = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} (E_\alpha \cap F_\alpha^c) = \left(\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha\right) \cap \left(\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha^c\right)$...? Why is it wrong?

Comment: @Shai... can you help me too with the comment above?

Comment: I think the problem is that the following is not necessarily true: $$\bigcup (A \cap B ) = \left( \bigcup A \right) \cap \left( \bigcup B \right) $$ because the right hand side is not necessarily contained in the left hand side. If $ x \in  \left( \bigcup A \right) \cap \left( \bigcup B \right) $ then $x \in A_{i}$ and $x \in B_{j}$ for some $i,j$ but this doesn't mean that $x \in A_{i} \cap B_{i}$ for any particular $i$ so it may not be in $\bigcup (A \cap B)$

Comment: @Shai your example for 2 does not work, since  $\displaystyle\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} (E_\alpha - F_\alpha)=\{2\}\cap\{3\}=\emptyset=\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha - \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha$.

Comment: You are right! I misread the $\bigcap$ for a $\bigcup$ on the left hand side of 2.

Answer (score 2):

If $\Gamma$ is a indexing set and $\{E_\alpha; \alpha \in \Gamma \}$ and $\{F_\alpha; \alpha \in \Gamma \}$ are families of subsets of a set $X$, then

> **1.** $\phantom{mm}$ $\displaystyle\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} (E_\alpha - F_\alpha) \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha - \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha$

**Proof:** If $x\in \displaystyle\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} (E_\alpha - F_\alpha)$ then, there is an $\alpha_0 \in \Gamma$ such that  $x\in E_{\alpha_0}$ and  $x\notin F_{\alpha_0}$. So $x\in \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha $ and $x\notin  \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha$. So we have $x\in \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha - \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha$.

The reverse inclusion does NOT hold.

**Counterexemple:** Let $A$ be a non empty set. Let $\Gamma=\{a,b\}$ and $E_a=F_a=A$ and $E_b=F_b=\emptyset$. Then

$\displaystyle\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} (E_\alpha - F_\alpha)=\emptyset \neq A = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha - \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha$

On the other hand, we have

> **2.** $\phantom{mm}$ $\displaystyle\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} (E_\alpha - F_\alpha) = \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha - \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha$

**Proof:** ($\subseteq$)If $x \in \displaystyle\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} (E_\alpha - F_\alpha)$, then, for all $\alpha \in \Gamma$, $x \in E_\alpha$ and $x\notin F_\alpha$. So $x \in \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha$ and $x \notin \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha$. So we have $x\in \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha - \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha$.

($\supseteq$)If $x\in \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha - \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha$ then, $x \in \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha$ and $x \notin \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha$. So, 
for all $\alpha \in \Gamma$, $x \in E_\alpha$ and $x\notin F_\alpha$. So, for all $\alpha \in \Gamma$, $x \in E_\alpha - F_\alpha$. So we have $x \in \displaystyle\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} (E_\alpha - F_\alpha)$.

**Remark:** In the proof of item 2, note that the proof of the ($\supseteq$) part is essentially the reverse implications used in the proof of the ($\subseteq$) part.

The proof of item 1 does not allow a similar "reversal", because, from $x\in \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} E_\alpha $ and $x\notin  \bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha$, we can get only that there are $\alpha_0, \alpha_1 \in \Gamma$ such that  $x\in E_{\alpha_0}$ and  $x\notin F_{\alpha_1}$, but we have no way to conclude that $\alpha_1=\alpha_0$.